# Python loop programming , loop not running

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python and although I'm typing word for word from the tutorial I'm not getting the result I should be. Basically I'm expecting multiple answers from the range, but I only get one result.

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> for i in range (10): sum = sum + i
>>> print (sum)    
45
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `I'm expecting multiple answers from the range`. Are you trying to print all the number b/w `0-10` than you should do `for i in xrange(10): print i`

Comment: Why would you get more than one result? The question is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's so basic. If you want to learn Python, you would be better off reading a book. Now, if the tutorial you were following doesn't make sense, you should find another one and keep reading until you grasp the basic principles of Python. That way, once you get *really* stuck, you can come to us and we'll be happy to help you. :)

Comment: You're going wrong by going against the grain of every tutorial I have ever seen and trying to invent your own coding style before you even know the basics.

Comment: The Alison tutorial I was following was here: http://alison.com/topic/learn/2971/36732/module-1-introduction-to-programming-with-python/for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 8):

***Note*** that using `sum` is a bad idea since [sum()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) is already a Python built-in function. I use `total` here instead:

```
total = 0
for i in range(10): 
    total = total + i  # same as total += i
    print(total)
```

gives:

```
0
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
```

Is this the output you expected/wanted?

In Python whitespace/indentation is *crucial*, so if you want a statement to be part of a function/loop/etc you need to indent it to the same level as the other statements in the block.

In contrast, your original code looks like this formatted more conventionally:

```
total = 0
for i in range(10): 
    total = total + i  # same as total += i
print(total)
```

So you can see that `print` was only called *once* after the loop had finished executing. *Indentation* makes all the difference between the two versions.

*Finally*,  [PEP8 - The Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) mentions that there ought to be [no space between the function name and its arguments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves), so `range(10)` is preferred to `range (10)`, `print()` to `print ()`, etc

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) is good reading for any Python programmer.

Comment: Much appreciated, but even copying your code line for line its printing one single answer, 45 and not the rest of the range. The tutorial I was following was from Alison (http://alison.com/topic/learn/2971/36732/module-1-introduction-to-programming-with-python/for-loops-in-python) and they use "SUM" rather than total, and I still only get 45 and none of the other results. Very frustrating.

Comment: @endarandom ok, my first segment *will* work (I tested it and the output you see is what it generated). I wonder if when you copy/paste it you get some mix of tabs and blanks which is hard to spot. Since the code is very short, I would suggest you just type in those few lines. If you are executing them line by line, be sure you indent. Are you working under Windows? Are you using IDLE?

Comment: @endarandom Let me know how you make out -- this is fairly straight forward so we ought to get this working. I wonder about the tutorial though ... here's the official [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) in case you want to check that out.

Answer (score 2):

That is in fact the correct answer you should be expecting. [Here's proof](http://jsfiddle.net/k38Js/) (hope you don't mind a little JS to prove my point)

Now, if you want the `sum` variable to be printed every iteration of the loop, you should modify your code to look like this:

```
sum = 0
for i in range (10):
    sum = sum + i
    print (sum)
```

Spacing is important in Python. Very important.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong here. In each step you're adding the next number to sum, so in each step it's 0, 1, 3, 6, ...., 45. And then you print that answer out.

If you want every step printed out, you need to make sure print is inside the for block:

```
for i in range (10):
    sum = sum + i
    print (sum)
```

(watch out for indentation)

PS. Don't use `sum` as a variable name. It's already a global function, so by assigning `sum=0` you're removing the old meaning - check `sum(range(10))` in a new python shell